# Infinite loading in Jenkins when slaves are upgraded to Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins

Our team has upgraded our slaves (Windows) from Python 2 to 3. When we try to run our Jenkins jobs, automated test cases were run successfully but we were stuck in xUnitIgnoredTests.py when this part is executing. Infinite loading is encountered when running the job.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um5CU.png)

We have upgraded our python file with Python 3 syntax. Is there any setup that might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include code or commands as text, not in the form of images.

Answer (score 0):

RDP/connect to an agent and run the command directly.  You might be able to get better console output that way.
If you still have Python2 on them run the script with that interpreter too to ensure that something else hasn't changed on the agent that is affecting the script.